# Is it possible to retrieve the data by using Recuva software

Tags: data-recovery

while installing ubuntu, I have lost all the data, which I had stored in my d drive, when I was using Windows 7. Is it possible to retrieve the data by using Recuva software.

Thanks.

Comment: No, because that runs on windows.

Comment: is there any other software, which may help me..

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu

Comment: can you specify the file-system of the d: drive you have lost??

Answer (score 0):

To retrive data form a drive there are two ways in ubuntu depending upon the file system the drive contained.
1) If file system was ext4/ext3 it is possible by

`extundelete`

to know more about this read type on your terminal

```
sudo man extundelete
```

2) If file system you were working with was ntfs we have a command as

```
ntfsundelete
```

to know more about this type following on your terminal

```
sudo man ntfsundelete
```

To know every detail of command for extundelete see [this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/extundelete.1.html)

To know more about ntfsundelete see [this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/ntfsundelete.8.html)